# Django: validate that a combination of modelform values is unique

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, and I've created a form where people can sign up for meal shifts. For each of the four days of the camping trip, there are two meals, and there are four shifts for each meal. My modelform is working, and the data is displaying, but I can't figure out - after extensive searching - how to ensure that people can only sign up for unclaimed shifts.

When the form is submitted, the data cleaning should check that no combination of the values already exists in the database.  I'm using django 1.8.

models.py

```
class mealShifts(models.Model):
    Sunday = "Sunday"
    Monday = "Monday"
    Tuesday = "Tuesday"
    Wednesday = "Wednesday"
    Thursday = "Thursday"
    Friday = "Friday"
    Days = (
        (Sunday, "Sunday"),
        (Monday, "Monday"),
        (Tuesday, "Tuesday"),
        (Wednesday, "Wednesday"),
        (Thursday, "Thursday"),
        (Friday, "Friday"),
        )
    Breakfast = "Breakfast"
    Dinner = "Dinner"
    Meals = (
        (Breakfast, "Breakfast"),
        (Dinner, "Dinner"),
        )
    Chef = "Chef"
    Sous_Chef = "Sous-Chef"
    KP ="KP"
    Shifts = (
        (Chef, "Chef"),
        (Sous_Chef, "Sous_Chef"),
        (KP, "KP"),
        )
    assigned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    day = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices=Days, default=Sunday)
    meal = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices=Meals, default=Dinner)
    shift = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices=Shifts, default=KP)
    camper = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default="none")
```

forms.py:

class MealForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = mealShifts
    fields = '__all__'
def clean(self):
    #modelform cleaning happens, but how?
```

views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MealForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            mealshifts = form.cleaned_data['mealShifts']
            return index(request)
    else:
        form = MealForm()
    return render_to_response('signup.html', RequestContext(request, {'form':form},))
```

Comment: Use [unique together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together) on the model fields

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    #check whether data is present as your wish 
    #if exists raise Validation error.
    return super(MealForm, self).clean()
```